# Boxes in LaTeX not proper

Tags: pdftex, boxes

```
\setlength\fboxrule{2pt}\setlength\fboxsep{2mm}
\fbox{ Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f$ is infinitely differentiable, \\ then prove that $f$ coincides with a polynomial.}
```

When i use this command, boxes are being created but the text is not aligning properly, means the text doesn't take the next line automatically it continues in some erratic manner. I hope someone is able to understand what i want to say.

Comment: You'd be best off creating a minimal example. What's needed is a complete `.tex` file which both manifests the problem and includes nothing not required to make the problem occur.

Comment: Why do you have the `\ ` after the comma? That's going to put two spaces, the first one of which will be slightly larger because it comes after the comma, the second will be a normal intrasentence space. As a side note, your mathematical statement is incorrect.

Comment: Why did you use a blockquote (`> `) instead of a code block (indent with four spaces by selecting code and clicking the toolbar button consisting of 1s and 0s)?

Comment: Also `\colon` not `:`. The usual `:` has the wrong spacing for function definitions (but correct spacing for e.g. `$\{ x : x > 0 \}$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe isn't improper; it's normal behavior for \fbox, which does not put its text in paragraph mode.

You either need to use a parbox inside the fbox, as so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \noindent\setlength\fboxrule{2pt}\setlength\fboxsep{2mm}% 
    \newlength{\boxwidth}%
    \setlength{\boxwidth}{\textwidth}%
    \addtolength{\boxwidth}{-2\fboxrule}%
    \addtolength{\boxwidth}{-2\fboxsep}%
    \fbox{\parbox{\boxwidth}{Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f$ is infinitely differentiable, \ then prove that $f$ coincides with a polynomial.}}
\end{document}
```

Or better, yet use the [framed](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed) package and its namesake environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,framed}
\begin{document}
    \setlength{\FrameRule}{2pt}
    \setlength{\FrameSep}{2mm}
    \begin{framed}
        \noindent Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f$ is infinitely differentiable, \ then prove that $f$ coincides with a polynomial.}
    \end{framed}
\end{document}
```